# Selection Box around android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat

Tags: android, widget, material-design, switchcompat

I am trying to mimic the new material design switch in my app and the switchcompat works pretty well. The only problem is a grey selection box appears around the switch on touch and really takes away from the clean look. Is this something I can remove?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat 
    ...
    android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: It should be noted that doing this removes some of the "Material Design-ness" on Android 5.x devices.  It's probably best  to encapsulate this in a style and use a styles-v21.xml that does not null the background to guarantee that your UI looks its best on Android 5.x.