# Using the Material Design Switch Toggle on previous versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-2.2-froyo, android-appcompat, material-design

I am creating a material design app while using the AppCompat support library to support devices running froyo and up. I have came across a challenge, since i am creating a material design app, i need to use the material design elements. Is there any way to use the [Material Design Switch](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch) on devices that are not running lollipop?

Comment: You can use SwitchCompat. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999583/selection-box-around-android-support-v7-widget-switchcompat

Answer (score 5):

You need to use...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ...
  android:background="@null" />
```